# callback?: (any) => void what this code mean?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, anonymous-function

i'm a newbie in javascript and angular, so i'm learning these.
could anybody interpret below code snippet for me?

```
public loadDataForPage(page: number, pageSize: number, callback?: (any) => void) {
   this._http.get(this._buildDataUrl(page, pageSize))
   .subscribe((data: any) => {
      const startIndex = (page-1) * pageSize;
      this._updateData(data, startIndex);
      this._data.next(data);
      callback({data});
   });
}
```

i don't know this part
***callback?: (any) => void           and callback({data});***

thanks.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#writing-the-function-type

Comment: This simply means the callback?: (any) => void which you will pass to loadDataForPage method should be of type void that means the callback function should not return any value.